# If $y=f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, make a conjecture about $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ and prove using induction

Tags: calculus, induction

If $y =y=f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, make a conjecture about the $n$ th derivative, $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ and prove your conjecture by using mathematical induction, where $n$ is an element of the real positive integers.

So I start by generating some values:

for $n = 1
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}$

for $n = 2 \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2} = \frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)^3}$

for $n = 3 \frac{d}{dx}\frac{2}{\left(1-x\right)^3} = \frac{6}{\left(1-x\right)^4}$

then I conclude that:

$\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}=\:\frac{n!}{\left(1-x\right)^{n+1}}$

My problem is proving by induction, I am stuck at the $n=k+1$ part. Can someone please provide some guidance to this? I don't know how to find the derivative for the $n!$ part.

Comment: what's the derivative of $n!/(1-x)^{n+1}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I don't know, can you find the derivative of a factorial?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk The variable is $x$. $n$ is just a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You are differentiating wrt $x$ and $k!$ is a constant. So $$\frac{d^{k+1}y}{dx^{k+1}}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d^ky}{dx^k}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{k!}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$
$$=k!\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)^{-(k+1)}=k!(k+1)(1-x)^{-(k+1)-1}$$
$$=\frac{(k+1)!}{(1-x)^{k+2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thus, by Principle Of Mathematical Induction, we have proved the claim